# Sort a nested array and return top 10 in elastic

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch

I have a nested data type in an elastic index and want to sort this ascending for all returned results. I have tried the following:

```
GET indexname/_search
{
                "_source" : ["m_iTopicID", "m_iYear", "m_Companies"],
                "query": {
                    "terms":{
                        "m_iTopicID": [11,12,13]
                    }
                },
   "sort" : [
       {
          "m_Companies.value" : {
             "order" : "asc",
             "nested_path" : "m_Companies"
          }
       }
    ]
}
```

The mapping of the index as follows:

```
{
  "indexname": {
    "mappings": {
      "topicyear": {
        "properties": {
          "m_Companies": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
              "name": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "value": {
                "type": "float"
              }
            }
          },
          "m_People": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
              "name": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "value": {
                "type": "float"
              }
            }
          },
          "m_Places": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
              "name": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "value": {
                "type": "float"
              }
            }
          },
          "m_Subtopics": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "m_fActivation": {
            "type": "float"
          },
          "m_iDocBodyWordCnt": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "m_iNodeID": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "m_iTopicID": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "m_iYear": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "m_szDocID": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "m_szDocTitle": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "m_szGeo1": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
              "name": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "value": {
                "type": "float"
              }
            }
          },
          "m_szSourceType": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
              "name": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "value": {
                "type": "float"
              }
            }
          },
          "m_szSrcUrl": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "m_szTopicNames": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This returns all topics with ID 11, 12 or 13 with a list of m_Companies... but the lists aren't sorted ascending by the value field.

I would then like to only return the top 10 of each list. So the list doesn't return hundreds like currently but just n. If I can't achieve this option I will just obtain the top 10 at the front-end with a javascript splice(0,10) but it would be great if elastic could do this for me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post your mappings and a sample document?

Comment: @user3775217 Yes I have added the mappings now.

Comment: i have posted a query to help this, let me know thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you provided the sort in the main/parent level query, this will sort only the parent/root documents. As you might have observed with the results that documents are sorted with minimum value for m_Companes.value.

To sort the nested documents for each document you have to go deep inside the nested document and apply sort as m_Companies are subdocuments in the parent document. You have to use nested inner_hits and then sort the [inner_hits](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-inner-hits.html).

This [github](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/9305) issue has very good example of what i was trying to explain as how this sorts only the parent/root document based on values in nested documents.

Since you want all documents in nested, so you can let the nested query to fetch all nested documents using match_all and sort based on value field.

you can use the following query

```
{
    "_source": ["m_iYear", "m_Companies"],
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [{
                    "terms": {
                        "m_iTopicID": [11, 12, 13]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "nested": {
                        "path": "m_Companies",
                        "query": {
                            "match_all": {}
                        },
                        "inner_hits": {
                            "sort": [{
                                "m_Companies.value": "asc"
                            }]
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "sort": [{
        "m_Companies.value": {
            "order": "asc",
            "nested_path": "m_Companies"
        }
    }]
}
```

Hope this helps,
Thanks

Comment: And adding "size": 10 within inner_hits returns the top 10. This is perfect. Thanks!

Comment: yeah you can do pagination as well. Thanks