# Elasticsearch sort values in nested field

Tags: python-3.x, elasticsearch

Sup community.
I have a problem.
I'm using Elasticsearch 6.4

Part of my data structure:

```
{ "_id" : 1,
"dirs" : [
  {"date_since":"2018-01-01", "date_by":"2018-12-01", "dir_id": 1},
  {"date_since":"2017-05-01", "date_by":null, "dir_id": 2}
],
"cost": 100
}

{ "_id" : 2,
"dirs" : [
  {"date_since":"2016-01-01", "date_by":null, "dir_id": 3},
  {"date_since":"2015-05-01", "date_by":"2016-01-01", "dir_id": 4},
  {"date_since":"2016-05-01", "date_by":null, "dir_id": 5}
],
"cost": 200
}
```

I need to get docs desc sorted by cost and i need to sort values in dirs field by date_by field with nulls-first.

How can i sort values inside nested field and not to sort docs by this nested field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43440405/2255344
this contains an example of composing a ['nested' query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html) with 'sort' on '[inner_hits](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-inner-hits.html)'.

Comment: Thanx a lot. Really helped

Comment: you are welcome. you can also mark this answer as the right one :)